# Allow a user to select local images within a app Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a folder with about 30 image icons. I am trying to allow for the user to select one of the 30 "local" images as their profile picture. I am looking to come up with the best way to do this, however most tutorials are for accessing the camera roll and allowing the user to upload their photos.

I am looking to have a method, maybe a UICollectionView and allow them to select a image that will be the users icon. I understand how to pull in the images from the iPhone itself but the server that I am using is not coded currently to allow this process to happen.

What is the best way to use images that are within the app and allow them to be placed into a image view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UICollectionView` is the way to go.

You'll need to first load all the local avatar filenames. The following example will load all images in the app directory which start with `avatar-`, ignoring all retain `@2x.png` files.

```
func getAvatarFilenames() -> Array<String> {
    var avatarFileNames = Array<String>()
    var paths = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathsForResourcesOfType("png", inDirectory: nil)
    for path in paths {
        var imageName = path.lastPathComponent

        // ignore retina images as when the uiimage loads them back out
        // it will pick the retina version if required
        if (imageName.hasSuffix("@2x.png")) {
            continue
        }

        // only add images that are prefixed with 'avatar-'
        if (imageName.hasPrefix("avatar-")) {
            avatarFileNames.append(imageName)
        }
    }

    return avatarFileNames
}
```

You can then create a `UICollectionView` which loads each of the avatar filenames. Something like this to configure each cell (assuming your `AvatarCell` has an image with tag `1000` - or better yet, a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass).

```
var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("AvatarCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
var avatarImageView = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as UIImageView
avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: avatarFileNames[indexPath.row])
```